# Scheduler not available

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I created a simple quartz.net sample. A console app, a scheduler class and a class that does some logging. Logging is done every 5 min. When I run the sample, I see the following error - 
**Scheduler not available: 'No connection could be made because the target machine
 actively refused it 127.0.0.1:555'
Failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
it 127.0.0.1:555**
Any ideas what could be causing this? Project has reference to Quartz, Common.logging, common.logging.core and log4net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow the scheduler to access port 555 on the machine. It's either blocked by the firewall or you didn't configure the scheduler to enable remoting.

Here's how to enable remoting using the quartz.config file.

```
# export this server to remoting context
quartz.scheduler.exporter.type = Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz
quartz.scheduler.exporter.port = 555
quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName = QuartzScheduler
quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType = tcp
quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName = httpQuartz
```

Comment: I have created new inbound rule to allow 555 (tcp); it still doesn't work..how do I configure scheduler to enable remoting?

Comment: I've updated the answer with how to configure remoting on the scheduler

Comment: where to add the above lines?

Comment: they go in either the quartz.conig file or in the app.config, in the quartz section